# Automatically generating string variables based on condition using php,jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am working on a student user registration system, whereby a new student is assigned a
registration number depending on his department.

The following students are studying mechanical engineering (one student-ID per line):

```
BSME/010J/2012
BSME/011J/2012
BSME/012J/2012
```

Only the middle area changes (010,011,012,013...). The last part is the current year.

Each department has a unique way of giving registration numbers.
Is there a way a php code can generate these registration numbers based on 
a value one selects on the option? the following is my form:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="myForm"
    <select>
    <option>Mechanical</option>
    <option>Bcom</option>
    <button id="submit">Generate</button>
</form>
```

Comment: your HTML is invalid (the `form` tag is missing at least `>`, and `</select>` is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that a string always starts or ends with the same sequence (in this example: j) and has a number that is incremented, then you could request a custom sequence, in which a separate sequence may distinguish different types of students in this case (For example: F for freshman, SM for sophomore, J for Junior, SR for Senior, and C for continuing student). As long as you have a separate variable representing an integer, you could increment that number and concatenate the strings to produce the final unique string:

**HTML**

```
<!-- Form -->
<form action="process.php" method="GET" \>
<!-- Select Department -->
<select name="department">
<option value="BSME">What Ever this stands for</option>
<option value="nextD">Next Department</option>
<option value="anotherD">Another Department</option>
</select>

<!-- Enter Year (Not sure how this is determine, assuming input) -->
<input type="text" name="year" />

<!-- Apply Custom Sequence -->
<input type="text" name="customSequence" /> 

<!-- SUBMITION - Call Processing -->
<button type="submit" value="Generate" />
</form>
```

**PHP -  process.php **

```
// Initialize Values
$departmentFromSelect = $_GET['department'];
$yearFromForm = $_GET['year'];
$valueFromSequenceInput = $_GET['customSequence'];
// INTEGER TO INCREMENT WOULD HAVE TO BE STATIC OR GLOBAL
public static $integerToIncrement = 0;

// Call the function passing to generate next reg number
function generateRegistrationNumber() {
    // Increment integer for next value
    $integerToIncrement++;
    // Concatenate String
    $finalRegNum = $departmentFromSelect . "/" . $integerToIncrement . $valueFromSequenceInput . "/" . $year;
    return $finalRegNum;
}
```